# Adobe Flex: Platform specific assets

Tags: flash, apache-flex, builder, conditional-compilation, platform-specific

Is there any builtin way using flash builder to embed different assets (for instance, different screenshot images for a walkthrough screen) **at compile time** using conditional compiling?

Of course, you can **include both and instantiate just one of them in runtime**, but your package will be innecesarily big.

Of course, you can pass **different config parameters to the compiler and use conditionals**, but I am looking for a "native" way of doing it depending on the targetted platform.

Is it?

Comment: what do you mean by "native way of doing it"?

Comment: A similar alternative is to use resource bundles. Typically you'll do this for internationalization. But there's no reason that you can't create different resource bundles (for the same language) that contain different images. You would compile the resource bundles as separate SWF's, then load the appropriate resource bundle at run time. The only other option that comes to mind would be to use different config parameters when compiling (as you've stated above), however then you could script the build process with `ant` and have it pass in the appropriate compiler options for you automagically.